# trim validation is not working for array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have tried to add a default trim validation to array but I don't understand why it is not working out. should Iterate elements in array to add trim or will it apply to each element in collection? I trim the below code assuming that trim will work for array elements but it is not. Can some please tell me why this is happening.

model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const toDoSchema = new schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        require: [true, "title is required"],
        trim: true
        },
    tasks:{
        type:[String],
        trim: true
        }
    });
const toDoModel = mongoose.model("toDo", toDoSchema);
module.exports = toDoModel;
```

controller.js

```
//importing model
const toDoModel = require('../models/ToDoModel');

//creating controller function
const createToDoController = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
    const {title,tasks} = req.body;

    if(!title) //input validation
    { 
        throw new Error("Please provide the title");
    }
    const newToDo = await toDoModel.create({ title, tasks });
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "User Created Successfully",
        newToDo,
      });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Unable to perform create operation",
            error: err
        })
        res.send(err.message);
    } 

}
module.exports = createToDoController;
```

postman output:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `tasks: [{
  type: String,
  trim: true
}]`?

Comment: nope, but after your comment I did and it worked Thank you so. looks like for fields it follow object notation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const toDoSchema = new schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        require: [true, "title is required"],
        trim: true
        },
    tasks:[{   type: String,   trim: true }]

    });
const toDoModel = mongoose.model("toDo", toDoSchema);
module.exports = toDoModel;
```

*Credits and special thanks to **@Marc***